# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy & Google Docs View

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a number of .doc documents on an S3 bucket that can be accessed from our website. I also want to have the documents embedded in my web application so that they can be viewed using the Google viewer.

However, I cannot figure out the bucket policy to make this happen. I would welcome any ideas.

```
    {
  "Id": "Policy1558099599790",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1558099595743",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::demobucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": [
            "https://mywebsite.com/*",
            "https://docs.google.com/*"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Side-note: `Referer` can be easily faked. It is not a good form of security.

Comment: You could activate [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) and observe how the requests come from Google Docs. This might give you an idea of how this might be configured. It is doubtful that Google Docs would use a `Referer`, since it is their back-end servers that retrieve the document, not the web browser. You'd probably need to discover their IP address range. Worst case, you could generate a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that grants temporary access to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate an [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that provides time-limited access to a URL, while keeping the bucket fully private.

If Google Docs accepts the URL, there would be no need to use a Bucket Policy to grant access.